# How do you update this custom paint in Java?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt, paint

I have a GUI based game that is real time and uses a JPanel and JFrame. I currently have a overridden paintComponent which paints based on certain conditions in my code. For example:

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics gfx)
{
    super.paintComponent(gfx);
    gfx.setFont(new Font("default", Font.BOLD, 18));

    if (one)
    {
        //do something
    }

    else
    {
        // do something else
    }
}
```

This works once depending on the condition. I have implemented a mouse listener that I'd like to use for the statements so that if someone clicks on a certain part it shows something else. I'd like to go back and run the paintComponent again so that it paints over top of the old one. Does `paintComponent()` already loop? If not, how can you run the method in a loop?

Comment: No, `paintComponent(Graphics g)` does not loop. It is called only when the JVM calls it. You can suggest that it be called by calling `repaint()` (as per kittycat's answer, 1+), but even so, it's not guaranteed that it will be called, especially if several repaint calls have been made and are "stacked up".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can repaint by calling `repaint()`. You can do this in a loop by creating a timer to repaint it, or just call it when it needs to be updated (probably better if your code is simple enough)

**EDIT:** About when to use a timer:

The timer is not necessary. I used it in a game once because I was custom painting the entire window and there were dozens of always-changing things to paint, and calling `render()` every time would not make my CPU happy. For something simple, though, it is better to call `repaint()` only when something changes, because if nothing changed, you are wasting that much time repainting it.

Comment: Is the timer necessary? I've tried the repaint() method but I did not see any changes. And it's not as simple as I'd like, currently around 4,000 lines.

Comment: @AmpageGrietu: I don't think that your posted code and text is adequate to allow us to understand your problem enough to answer it. If you don't get a decent answer soon, consider creating and posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example Program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @AmpageGrietu What do you mean by 4000 lines?